# "signature is corrupt or invalid" downloading from IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, certificate

I got a Certum certificate to sign my C# application. Everything seems to be ok and I can execute the application and also see the valid certificate on it.

But, if I upload it to my webpage (publishing with Visual Studio or also uploading the EXE) I can't download it with Internet Explorer on Windows7. I get always this message: "Signature is corrupt or invalid". But once it is on the PC it seems to be valid. I know, there was a bug on IE in the year 2013 but it should be solved.

On Windows 10, Smartscreen also blocks this exe and I can't download it. I paid this certificate to show that my app is secure and now I got more problems than before :(

*I don't know if I can insert the link to my application here.*

**Edit**: I found this document from Microsoft:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32288.windows-enforcement-of-authenticode-code-signing-and-timestamping.aspx
- Seems that Microsoft with IE (but also Google with Chrome) doesn't allow to download SHA-1 signed applications anymore since 1. january because it is not secure enough.

Comment: 2 thumbs up for your finding. Some of our packages stopped being valid, even though we used the same certificate for the last 2 years. One of them was working (the only one timestamped last year). Searched a lot, tried many things, but im pretty confident you found the cause.

Answer (score 3):

OK, now I can say: **THERE IS NO SOLUTION**!

At least not for the moment (January 2016).

1. All new certificates must have a SHA-2 hash on Windows7/8 and Windows 10
2. [Certum](https://en.sklep.certum.pl/data-safety/code-signing-certificates/open-source-code-signing.html) <strike>doesn't have SHA-2 certificates for the OpenSource option</strike> Since february also the OpenSource certificate from Certum has SHA-2 hash possibility!

<strike>So, if you want create an application for WindowsXP, you can use the Open Source Sign from Certum. If you want sign your application for a new OS, you will only loose your money if you buy a Certum OpenSource certificate!</strike>

Comment: @torpederos: thank you, I will edit my post and correct it.

Comment: Is  "THERE IS NO SOLUTION" still correct? Shouldn't it be "There is a solution: renew your cert to get one using SHA-2"?

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove KB3124263 (had installed on the 14th for me) to return functionality :-(

Answer (score 0):

Even though my code signing certificate had a SHA2 hash, I still got the invalid or corrupt signature error when downloading the file in IE / Edge.

Apparently it is also required that the code signing certificate is issued by a CA with a SHA2 hash.

After contacting Verisign / Symantec support, they directed me to the following guide for reissuing my certificate:

- https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&id=SO21217

this changed my intermediary CA from "VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2010 CA" (SHA1) to "Symantec Class 3 SHA256 Code Signing CA" (SHA256), and now IE / Edge don't report any errors