# My signed executable is blocked in Internet Explorer even if it's signed with SHA2

Tags: code-signing-certificate

I've created and signed a new executable file (the file is signed with double signature SHA1 and SHA256 and timestamped).
Since 1/1/2016 if I try to download it from Internet Explorer (or Microsoft Edge) I get an error (saying the signature is corrupted).
Smartscreen also tells that the file is not signed.

If I look at the file from the properties, it has the two signatures.
Can you help me out understanding what's the problem?

Here's the link for the download [PhraseExpander setup file](http://www.phraseexpander.com/software/PhraseExpanderSetup.exe)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wrote here:
[valid certificate is corrupt with IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809705/signature-is-corrupt-or-invalid-downloading-from-ie)

I still doesn't have a solution, because I am not able to request a SHA-2 certificate. But you can't download any application from web with a SHA-1 certificate, anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Even if I though I was able to sign using SHA256 (and the signature appeared in the properties) the certificate wasn't capabale of using SHA256 and I had to get a new one.
Now things are working properly although the SmartScreen is still displayed after the download. If I got things properly, it shall go away in a few days after people download it.

Answer (score 0):

Class 3 certificates are a step above the Class 2. Class 2 does not require “Extended Validation”. However the “EV” code signing certificates combine all of the regular benefits of digitally-signed code with a rigorous extended validation process. They represent the gold standard for authentication and security in code signing certificates. EV code signing certificates adhere to strict validation standards from the CA/Browser Forum and to Microsoft specifications. Enhanced authentication is provided via an encrypted token containing the private key.