# Resolve "the signature of foo.exe is corrupt or invalid" in IE

Tags: signtool

When users try and download my installer, after download is complete, IE11 on Windows 10 presents the error "the signature of foo.exe is corrupt or invalid"

Signtool reports the signature to be valid. Microsoft confirms a bug in IE9 and IE10 could cause this issue (https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/800433/kb2870699-breaks-ie-msi-signature-validation) but as I'm seeing this in IE11 this could be a different issue.

Any other ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Is this the same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809705/signature-is-corrupt-or-invalid-downloading-from-ie

Comment: (Not enough reputation to comment, sorry for that.) I just want to bring attention to the matter of the starting date:
As specified in the link provided by ByteSmith, an SHA2 certificate must have a starting date younger than January 2016 the 1st (included), otherwise the same error will appears (in Edge as well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds as though you may have a CodeSign certificate that was issued before the new requirements for 2016 (including abandoning the use of SHA-1) that began enforcement on 2016-01-01. If this is the case, the simplest solution would be to have your CodeSign certificate reissued to meet the new requirements. *I'm going through the same process myself.

Take a look at this article: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32288.windows-enforcement-of-authenticode-code-signing-and-timestamping.aspx

Comment: Hello, your answer was very helpful, thanks! For the lazy readers (like me): notice the "/fd sha256" switch on SignTool.exe and dual-signing in the article referred.